# Crystal Reports - Dynamic Parameter, filter on description field

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

In a crystal report, I have a dynamic parameter that has a value and a description field. How do I apply the filter to my report based on the Description for the value selected?
E.G.
value1 - Description1
value2 - Description1
value3 - Description1
value4 - Description2

So If I choose value2 from my combo box, that Description1 is applied to the report filter. Please note, the value fields don't appear in my report at all, they are simply being used as a means of filtering by Description.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't really need the Value field in the dynamic parameter.
Reverse 'Value' and 'Description' or remove 'Value' from the dynamic parameter.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your reply. I found a solution. I need to use cascading parameters. My first parameter is on client, which then populates the second parameter, region. Then I can use region as a filter on the report. 

Now I am trying to figure out how to auto populate the region value, when the client is selected. At the moment when a client is selected, the region for the client is populated in the region drop down, but it still needs to be selected from the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use dynamic cascading parameters